# How to build AOSP's libhardware

Tags: android-ndk

I just cloned libhardware from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/
how do I build shared library out of this.

I tried using below command, 
`ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.`
but i see this message
"*Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I did not try to build libhardware standalone. I downloaded full AOSP project and build it using [official guide](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html). Yes, it will take a lot of time, but finally you get all libraries including libhardware :)